# How to use varchar in node.js sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm using `Sequelize 4.42.0` in `Node.js`, and I want to create some fields in `SQL Server 2014`, with type of `varchar(100)`.

According to the docs, `DataTypes.STRING` should be map to Varchar.

And I'm using below code:

```
const sequlize = new Sequelize("Test", "komeil", "1234", {
host: "localhost",
dialect: "mssql",
operatorsAliases: false,
define: {
    timestamps: false
}
,
logging: false
});
const User2 = sequlize.define("User2", {
Id: {
    type: Sequlize.STRING(100),
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
}       
}, { freezeTableName: true });
```

I expecting `varchar(100)` field, but it generates `nvarchar(100)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is an error in docs: see
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6036

Answer (score 0):

```
row_name: {
    type: "varchar(36)",
    allowNull: false
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. So if you use Sequlize.STRING(100) the value is matched from an enum which is NVARCHAR. but if  "varchar(100)" is entered this is ignored and applied as is and hence it works. In other words, you can put "dummy" instead of "varchar(100)" and sequelize will honour it but it will fail on the SQL server. Hope this helps!